# Python . Фильтрация по содержимому текстового файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, list

Есть список `black_list` со сслыками на страницы пользователей Вконтакте, которые не нужны.

С помощью условия `link not in black_list` происходит фильтрация пользователей.

Но постепенно в массив придется вносить очень много ссылок.

Как сделать условие для фильтрации по содержимому текстового файла?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Особо ничего не меняется, просто нужно дополнительно открыть файл :)

Если файл `blacklist.txt` такого формата:

```
id1
id2
id3
```

То можно сделать следующим образом:

```
link1 = 'id4'
link2 = 'id2'

with open('blacklist.txt', 'r') as blacklist:
    bad_users = blacklist.read().splitlines() # ['id1', 'id2', 'id3']
    print(link1 not in bad_users) # True
    print(link2 not in bad_users) # False
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!